# What's the difference between "благодарю" and "спасибо"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I rarely hear *благодарю*, so I was wondering under what circumstances would one use it as an expression of gratitude? Are *благодарю* and *спасибо* interchangeable?

Comment: No, these two are completely different, not even close. Maybe you confuse благодаря with благодарю?

Comment: @user31264 Actually no... well i'm using google's translation so maybe it's not accurate, nonetheless I can't understand the difference between them

Comment: If you're confused between благодар**ю** vs спасибо - the only difference is in style. `Благодарю` sounds a bit more formal than `спасибо`. Also see the other comment from @DK

Comment: @Vitaly Osipov What comment from DK??

Comment: @DouglasHeld It was here a year ago, no idea where it went. Likely the user deleted his account,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are interchangeable to a certain degree. `Благодарю` is much more formal. In some cases, it might also be considered more polite. This being said, `Спасибо` is absolutely "safe" and polite in any situation. When in doubt, I would suggest using `Спасибо`, as `Благодарю` may sound a bit awkward, outdated or even sarcastic (in certain contexts).
`Спасибо` could be translated as both `Thank you` and `Thanks`, while `Благодарю` only as `Thank you`.

Благодарю is still widely used in some fixed phrases like `"Благодарю за внимание"` (`Thank you for your attention`)

Comment: >Спасибо could be translated as both Thank you and Thanks, while Благодарю only as Thank you. I'm curious... what's the difference between thank you and thanks??

Answer (score 4):

Literally "благодарю" ~ "благо дарю" means "[I am] giving blessing [to you]" or "sharing good"

Whereas "Спасибо" ~ "спаси [тебя] Бог" means "[May] God save [you]"

Answer (score 3):

"Благодарю" means "I express thanks" while "спасибо" means "I'm glad".

The thing is, one can express thanks even if they're not really glad or for somebody else. This makes благодарю more formal and impersonal. "Okay, I don't really feel glad, but you did that for me so I'm expressing thanks for the sake of etiquette or whatever".

So, one can use благодарю, but not спасибо in a situation where:

1. Somebody gave you something you think you had a right to anyway.
2. Somebody gave you a gift that you don't like.
3. You're expressing thanks on behalf of someone else. A representative of a country or head of state can give thanks for a gift or service to his country with благодарю, but not with спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`Благодарю` is almost like `спасибо`, but a bit like you're wearing a top hat and using a walking stick. Someone would be considered as having a unique style (if they always use this word) or a bit fancy or just formal.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the detailed answer by Arthur Kazykhanov, I would mention that there exists a special environment where the use of «спасибо» is plainly prohibited. This is prison life and, generally, the criminal milieu. There, one should employ only «благодарю» (or «благодарствую», or «от души»). «Cпасибо» is taboo not only in the oral but also in the written version of that argot — both in illegally smuggled scribblings and legitimate letters. A prison proverb has it: "За «спасибо» ебут красиво."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the truth behind these two words is pretty interesting. Благодарю, in general, is a high vibrational word and is used everywhere спасибо is used, and now, people are using it more often because спасибо actually means спаси Бог in shortened which translation is God help, save me God etc. There's also a response to it: He за что.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native speaker and I'd say they're exactly the same and even interchangeable. The difference is that благодарю is a way more formal way of expressing thanks; it's more like 'I'm grateful to you.'

Answer (score -3):

Совершенно разные слова, связанные с долженствованием, обещаниями и выражением пожеланий.

Благо+дарю может означать в зависимости от ситуации или

"я ваш должник/у вас в долгу" - I owe you one, когда это произносит, например, подчиненный начальнику;

либо это может быть подтверждение статуса начальника, когда одно его слово - уже добрый знак расположения. В этом смысле начальник ничего не обещает и не дарит, а он и есть "благо" ну и это такая форма выражения превосходство, вы мне делаете что-то за то, что я дарю тебе свой свет/благо и тп. Обычно, в первом значении произносится в связке с нарицательным.

То есть, если:

> — Он поднял их и сказал с улыбкою милости: «Благодарю вас именем отечества».Н. М. Карамзин. Наталья, боярская дочь

> — Чувствительнейше благодарю вас милостивый государь, за то и за другое. А. А. Боратынский. Письма.

> — Madame! я благодарю вас за вашу учтивость. Д. И. Фонвизин. Бригадир (1783-1786)

> — Благодарю вас за этот подарок и в память дарю вас взаимно.  Ф. В. Булгарин. Иван Иванович Выжигин (1829)

Ну и тд., то есть - благодарю (кого?)/ благодарю за (какую-то вещь, знак, совершенный поступок).

"Благодарю." - без уточнения "за что" может звучать сухо и неблагодарно. Благодарю - это радостная эмоция.

"Спасибо" же дословно я бы перевел как - may God protect your thoughts or deeds; may God's will be so.

"Спасибо" часто лишено указания конкретного предмета "за что", потому что это не общение быть должным, а пожелание защиты или участия Бога.

Спасибо, что беспокоишься обо мне, не забываешь меня и тд. Спасибо касается в том числе духовных ценностей, а не стоимости вещей или услуг.

> — Спасибо, моя милая! какъ ты хорошо поешь! Шишков.

Если бы тут стояло *благодарю*, это было значило бы: пение закончилось, займемся чем-то другим. Но тут смысл - продолжай петь, пожалуйста, у тебя так хорошо это получается. То есть *благодарю* не всегда заменяет *спасибо*.

> — Спасибо, барин, — сказала старуха, — в этом теперь уж нет нужды. Радищев.

Тут тоже *спасибо* не заменишь *благодарю*, так как спасибо тут = нет, не нужна ваша помощь (Бог уже помог).

*Спасибо* произносится со спокойной, слегка положительной интонацией, обычно без пафоса. Слишком радостное или эмоциональное *спасибо* может изменить значение и эффект от сказано на противоположный.

Но в целом, *спасибо* можно говорить всегда, практически нет ситуаций, когда оно было бы неуместно, дело скорее в интонации. За исключением, разве что криминальной среды, где могут придираться к словам с целью унизить собеседника, подловив на шаблонной фразе, но это совсем другая история.

А вот *благодарю* уместно далеко не всегда. Употребляется в ситуациях с получением чего-то от другого. И кроме интонации довольства и радости, пояснением за что благодарю или кого благодарю не бывает. За исключением фраз вроде: благодарю, хватит! сказанных с раздражением, тогда благодарность перекрывается "хватит" и негативным тоном.